# Facebook Like Count Auto Refresh

Tags: php, facebook, json, api

I am new to working with the Facebook API and I have a question that I believe should be simple.

I am setting up a TV screen for a store that will display a webpage. On the page I am going to display the current 'like count' of the store's facebook page. I know how to set it up to display the likes but is there an easy way to have the number auto-refresh when new people like the page WITHOUT refreshing the whole page. I guess I'm looking for it to be generated dynamically. I'm not sure how to go about this. I'm willing to do the research, I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Here's the code in the body of the page so far:

```
<?php
function fan_count($fan_ID) {
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $fan_ID));
echo $info->likes;
}

function fan_name($fan_ID) {
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $fan_ID));
echo $info->name;
}
?>

<div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid black;">
    Facebook Logo
</div>
<div class="fb_stats" id="fb_name">
    <?php fan_name(PAGE_ID)?>
</div>
<div class="fb_stats" id="fb_likes">
    <?php fan_count(PAGE_ID)?>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

### EDIT

Alright, here is my updated code per the answer below. I can't get the PHP on the main page to work (I'll worry about the reloading once I have this bit set up correctly). I'm just looking to grab the like count for simplicities sake and I'll build from there. Here's my code (I'm using 'cocacola' as an example; vanity URLs are compatible with the Facebook graph btw):

```
<?php
class fanpage {
public $fan_ID;
public $info;

function __construct($fan_ID) {
    $this->fan_ID = $fan_ID;
    $this->info = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $fan_ID));
  }

function fan_count() {
   echo $info->likes;
  }
}

$fp = new fanpage(cocacola);
?>

<div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid black;">
    Facebook Logo
</div>
<div class="fb_stats" id="fb_likes">
    <?php $fp->fan_count()?>
    <span style="font-size:20px; position:absolute; top:400px;">Total Likes</span>
</div>
```

Does it possibly have anything to do with $info being defined in one function and trying to be called in another? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just updated some code below!**

---

**`fanpage.php`**

```
class fanpage {
  public $fan_ID;
  public $info;

  function __construct($fan_ID = null) {
    $this->fan_ID = $fan_ID;
    $this->info = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $fan_ID));
  }

  function fan_count() {
    return $info->likes;
  }

  function fan_name() {
    return $info->name;
  }
}
```

**`page.php`**

```
<?php
include('fanpage.php');
$fp = new fanpage(PAGE_ID);
?>

<div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid black;">
    Facebook Logo
</div>
<div class="fb_stats" id="fb_name">
    <?php echo $fp->fan_name()?>
</div>
<div class="fb_stats" id="fb_likes">
    <?php echo $fp->fan_count()?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript>
var delay = 10000; //10000 = 10 seconds
var fbint = window.setInterval(checkFacebook, delay);

function checkFacebook(){
  $.getJSON('checkFacebook.php?callback=?', {fan_ID: '$fan_ID'}, function(rs){
    if (rs.name) $('#fb_name').text(rs.name);
    if (rs.likes) $('#fb_likes').text(rs.likes);
  });
}
</script>
```

**`checkFacebook.php`**

```
include('fanpage.php');

$fan_ID = (int) $_GET['fan_ID'];
$fp = new fanpage($fan_ID);

$data = (object) array('likes' => $fb->likes, 'name' => $fb->name); //sloppy object
$callback = $_GET['callback']; //sanitize this

print $callback . '(' . json_encode($data) . ')';
exit;
```

---

**Old stuff below**

---

Are you familiar with much JavaScript or jQuery? Here's a short jQuery example that should work fine.

Let's assume the snipped above is from `page.php`. Include jQuery and add this below it:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
var delay = 10000; //10000 = 10 seconds
var fbint = window.setInterval(checkFacebook, delay);

function checkFacebook(){
  $.getJSON('checkFacebook.php?callback=?', function(rs){
    if (rs.name) $('#fb_name').text(rs.name);
    if (rs.likes) $('#fb_likes').text(rs.likes);
  });
}
</script>
```

This checks `checkFacebook.php` once every 10 seconds. If it gets a `name` or `likes` attribute back it will update them automatically. Now we need to actually build the `checkFacebook.php` page out!

```
//do all your normal config stuff here
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $fan_ID));

$data = (object) array('likes' => $info->likes, 'name' => $info->name); //sloppy object
$callback = $_GET['callback']; //sanitize this

print $callback . '(' . json_encode($data) . ')';
exit;
```

One more thing! Your functions at the top work fine but you are wasting a lot of time by sending the exact same request twice. You can pull both pieces of information from the same place, so why not do something like this instead?

```
<?php
class fanpage {
  public $fan_ID;
  public $info;

  function __construct($fan_ID = null) {
    $this->fan_ID = $fan_ID;
    $this->info = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $fan_ID));
  }

  function fan_count() {
    return $info->likes;
  }

  function fan_name() {
    return $info->name;
  }
}

$fp = new fanpage(PAGE_ID);
?>

<div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid black;">
    Facebook Logo
</div>
<div class="fb_stats" id="fb_name">
    <?php echo $fp->fan_name()?>
</div>
<div class="fb_stats" id="fb_likes">
    <?php echo $fp->fan_count()?>
</div>
```

This way your server doesn't have to call out to Facebook to request the same info twice :)

Comment: Oh wow, ok! I'm definitely familiar with Javascript and jQuery but am in that phase where I can understand the language if I read it but can't necessarily just write it out from scratch. I totally get what you're doing here which looks like it should work great. Let me try it out and see what happens and then I'll come back and accept your answer!

Comment: A couple question as I dig deeper into this code. 1) Why are you using $fan_ID = null in your function __construct() instead of just $fan_ID? 2) $fan_ID is not being defined in checkFacebook.php. Does it not need to be defined because when checkFacebook.php is being called, $fan_ID has already been defined as a global variable? 3) I want the fan_count to display so I'm assuming I need to change `return $info->likes;` to `echo $info->likes;` , correct? I can't get it to work, I will post my code above (I've proofread it a bunch and in theory it should work but I can't see what I'm missing).

Comment: @MxmastaMills Good questions! 1) You can actually remove that, it's a habit of mine. It sets `$fan_ID` to null if you don't send a value through. 2) If `$fan_ID` needs to be dynamic it should probably get passed through the ajax call, I'm going to update the answer now. 3) Yep, my bad! I'm updating that part now to have a print in the view portion instead so you can access those without printing them if you need to.